# Resume from suspend close all programs

Tags: suspend, asus

I have an Asus K550J.
Whenever you suspend either via command line (pm-suspend) even through lid, apparently okay because of blinking LEDs.
But when I restart the PC all programs were open are closed, as if it had just been started and has not recovered!

I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 in dualboot with Windows 10.

Linux asus 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[Output from hwinfo](http://pastebin.com/DdnXBQgg)

[Output from lshw](http://pastebin.com/PifQVuMD)

**Settings screenshot:**

[image: Here the screen of my settings]

**Tweak Settings screenshot:**

[image: Here the screen of my tweak settings]

What have I to do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In All Settings>Power,  ensure that the option `when the lid is closed` is set to `Suspend`.

Comment: @Rahul Hi, thanks for your answer but I think options are quite right!!! I added screenshots on my question and some other info.

Comment: can you try a different Ubuntu version on a USB if you have the bandwidth to download? Possibly 16.04 or 14.04?

Comment: @MarkYisri Yes I can! I have a Lubuntu USB already ready!

Comment: @Cirelli94 great, go ahead and try it then.

Comment: Suspending shouldnt interfere with programs. It is possible they get moved off screenor get unregistered with x server. Try running firefox then suspend and resume and check processes with ps -ef command if firefox is still running. If it is so, we could write a script that raises those programs from the dead,so to speak

Comment: @Serg hmm, interesting suggestion! We'll have to try that if Lubuntu doesn't work!

Comment: @Cirelli94 Okay, finally got back here after posting and discussing over 2 Meta questions ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287575/340193), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287574/340193)). How did the suspend work?

Comment: @MarkYisri It doesn't work! I close the lid, it suspend, than I reopen but it starts as it has been switched off!

Comment: @Serg I did as you suggest but firefox wasn't still running! [before](http://pastebin.com/VkqzE4jm) [after](http://pastebin.com/ujFdqWJC)

Comment: @Cirelli94 strange. it's like suspend causes shutdown. I'll look into this further.

Comment: @MarkYisri yes!!! But the led on the pc for the suspension blinks! (i added a little detail: dualboot fin windows 10)

Comment: Try taking a peak into the logs, `grep -i -A 5 'suspend' /var/log/syslog` , let us know if you find anything suspicious.

Comment: I applied [this](http://kb.monitorware.com/kbeventdb-detail-id-6904.html) for dev/xconsole problems and now the log appear:   http://pastebin.com/bfkNKsdq

Answer (score -1):

[Update Linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296424/203821)

Several people are having issues with the kernel in 16.04.

I would suggest an update. Worked for me.

Comment: I'm on 16.10 with 4.8.0 Kernel. I'll update soon to 4.8.10...

Comment: Linux 4.8.10-040810-generic here now, but it doesn't solve anything!