# Problem resuming after suspend in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shutdown

I've recently upgraded my Asus laptop from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04. Suspend was working fine on 17.10. However, after the upgrade, whenever I try to resume the laptop after suspending, the laptop shows a black screen with a pointer flickering at the top. It stays like this for 10 seconds before it turns on. But when it turns on I find that all the applications that were running are closed as if the laptop has just restarted. Can anybody help?
The laptop is Core-i5 with 4GB of RAM

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/853042/resume-from-suspend-close-all-programs

Comment: Yeah I've checked this out before but my laptop is already up-to-date

Comment: Hi idk - do you have nVidia graphics on your machine? There's a bit of discussion about suspend issues being fixed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend/1043397#1043397 but this doesn't sound similar to anything previously mentioned. Perhaps the nouveau.modeset=0 fix might help if you've got nVidia graphics? Using an older kernel might provide a temporary fix - if you've just upgraded you should still have a 4.14 kernel that can be selected from 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' in the grub menu.

Comment: I'm also attempting to gather suspend issues together in this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562&p=13780724#post13780724

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device)

Comment: Duplicate of many! Largest collection of answers I found was here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend. Added mine there: https://askubuntu.com/a/1209099/165265.